# Styling enumerate environment from the enumitem package

Tags: enumerate

I am trying to style the [`enumerate`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures) environment from the `enumitem` package... I want basically that the enumeration is not too to the left, for example I don't want something like this:

[image]

I would like to be able also to increase the size of the items (the font size) and maybe insert a line break after `Exercise 1`.

Is that possible to do? Or are there any other easy alternatives?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: It is possible, but  isn't it semantically better to use a theorem-like structure?

Comment: If you declare something like  `\newtheorem{Ex}{Exercise}`you don't have to make the enumeration by yourself…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possibilities with `enumitem`: I define two enumerate-like lists, `exercicese`and `otherexs$, with different formattings. For the  environment with a linebreak after the label, you can have some control on the vertical spacing between the label and the  item, patching the \item command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{label =Exercise \arabic*, wide = 0pt, labelwidth = \linewidth, format = \apptocmd{\item}{\leavevmode\vskip\dimexpr-\baselineskip \relax}{}{}\bfseries}
\newlist{otherexs}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[otherexs]{label =Exercise \arabic*. , wide = 0pt, font =\color{red}\Large\scshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exercises}{\apptocmd{\item}{\leavevmode\vskip\dimexpr-\baselineskip \relax}{}{}} \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{exercises}
\item Prove Fermat’s small theorem.
\item Prove Fermat’s last theorem.
\end{exercises}

\begin{otherexs}
  \item Prove Fermat’s small theorem.
  \item Prove Fermat’s last theorem.
\end{otherexs}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you mean increasing the label font size, yes. See my updated answer.